# How to run expressions or functions in order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make my rails app to run functions in order? I like to have function A finish running before function B begins running.

Comment: If you aren't using threads you can call one and after call another sequentially. 
my_functionA()
my_funcitonB()

Comment: Some some example code, it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using threads, the code below would run sequentially.

```
def foo
  puts("foo")
end

def bar
  puts("bar")
end

foo
bar
```

Comment: Minor note, but it's an important element of Ruby style: Omit empty parentheses on method calls. It's just `foo` and `bar` at the end.

Comment: @tadman Indeed, thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer accordingly.